# React awesome slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need that when adding new data, the slider does not start spinning again, but continues adding new pages for new data, thanks in advance

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/getData', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })

                const dataJson = await response.json()
                const groupKZ = []
                const groupRU = []

                const kz = dataJson.map(item => {
                    const {ret_ru_status, ...newItem} = item
                    return newItem
                })
                groupKZ.push(kz)

                const ru = dataJson.map(item => {
                    const {ret_status_kz, ...newItem} = item
                    return newItem
                })
                groupRU.push(ru)

                const all = [...groupKZ[0], ...groupRU[0]]

                setDataKZ(all)
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error)
            }
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    const Auto = withAutoplay(AwesomeSlider)

    return (
        <Auto play={true} cancelOnInteraction={false} interval={2000} bullets={false} buttons={false} infinite>
            {data.map((val, idx) => {
                return <div key={idx}>
                    text
                </div>
            })}
        </Auto>
    )
```

that is, I will have a function called every minute

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { withAutoplay, AwesomeSlider } from 'react-awesome-slider';
import 'react-awesome-slider/dist/styles.css';

const YourComponent = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/getData', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                });

                const dataJson = await response.json();
                // Process data and update without resetting
                updateData(dataJson);
            } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    // Function to update data without resetting the slider
    const updateData = newData => {
        setData(prevData => [...prevData, ...newData]);
    };

    // Auto is the slider component
    const Auto = withAutoplay(AwesomeSlider);

    return (
        <Auto play={true} cancelOnInteraction={false} interval={2000} bullets={false} buttons={false} infinite>
            {data.map((val, idx) => {
                return <div key={idx}>{/* Render your content here based on the new data */}</div>;
            })}
        </Auto>
    );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

Data is saved in the state using the `useState`. The first value is an empty field.

`UseEffect` fetches the data and calls `updateData` function to add the new data to your existing data state.

`AwesomeSlider` component renders the new data.

This means that when the new data is received and added to the current data state, the slider will not reset.

Instead, it will continue to show the existing slides alongside the new ones.

Adjust the rendering part within `data.map` to show your content according to the new data received.